# React not rendering all elements in UI

Tags: reactjs, backbone.js

I am working on an application where we use Backbone and then render React inside some of the Backbone views (basically transition from Backbone to React slowly). I am having an issue where I have buttons on a header that are controlled by Backbone, that cause changes in the UI built out of React Elements. For several internal reasons we have to use React 15. The problem is it works on the first visit to the view, but if I leave the view to go to another view and then come back to the same view, clicking the button causes React to render (good) but the added UI elements are not rendered anywhere in the UI.

For simplicity sake I am just trying to add a simple div. Here is the workflow

0. Navigate to backbone/react view
1. Click button in backbone
2. Button emits an event
3. React listening for event
4. React adds new div to in render and the div shows up on the page as expected
5. Use browser back button to leave view
6. URL changes and backbone loads a different view
7. Navigate back to backbone/react view
8. Click button in backbone
9. Button emits an event
10. React listening for event
11. React renders but new div is not added to the page

### What I have checked

1. Looking at the object generated by React render, the new div is indeed there in both cases
2. Scanned DOM, gave div some unique text, it is not in DOM

I have not shown any code because there would simply be to much, I am more looking for ideas, or under what conditions, React might fail to add some elements in the UI even when the React render returns that element in the object the render function generates. Or on the other hand, maybe it is something in Backbone limiting React, I cannot be sure.

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
```

Any thoughts or avenues for exploration would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you call unmountComponentOnNode?

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov no I have not, but I will look into that thanks for the tip!

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov  React.unmountComponentAtNode(); is not a method in react 15.6. Thanks for the idea anyway!

Comment: react is not supposed to work with dom. it's a method of [react-dom](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode)

Comment: I solved the issue. Somehow reactDom was deciding not to render the modal even though the render method was returning the components as expected. The work around was to store the React component returned from ReactDom.render as a variable in backbone, and then manipulate its state there instead of inside the actual React component.

Comment: How did you pass props to your component?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. Somehow reactDom was deciding not to render the modal even though the render method was returning the components as expected. The work around was to store the React component returned from ReactDom.render as a variable in backbone, and then manipulate its state there instead of inside the actual React component.

In Backbone:

```
this.component = ReactDOM.render( ...)
```

and then when the button is pressed (which is handled by Backbone):

```
handleConfigure: function() {
        this.component.setState({ 'showConfigModal': !this.component.state.showConfigModal });
      },
```